# Does Python's ThreadPoolExecutor shrink a thread pool eventually?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am looking for a Thread Pool implementation in Python that is able to dynamically grow/shrink the number of threads that it's using. Looking at `ThreadPoolExecutor`, it doesn't seem like it shrinks dynamically. See the [worker thread code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L70-L110).

Is there an alternative that will allow idle threads to die if there's no work to match them? Is there a bug to track this feature for the existing executor?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't shrink the pool. Basically I don't see a point to do so. So I believe there is no such implementation in Python.

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for a ready solution for your idea of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install threadpool_executor_shrink_able.
```

Its api is like concurrent.futures.ThreadpoolexExecutor in that it can auto shrink and grow. If a thread is free for more than 60 seconds, it will terminate. If there are many tasks to be run at one time, it will grow to the maxinum number of threads.